# using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient

Tags: c#, connection

I have a problem with c#.Net.I want to connect to analysis service.I use this code:

```
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;

AdomdConnection con = new AdomdConnection("Provider=msolap; Data Source = RR-Vaio;" + "Initial Catalog =Project1");
```

But it has error:

> "The type or namespace name'AnalysisServices' does not exist in the
>   namespace'Microsoft'(are you missing Form1.cs an assembly reference?)

Thanks

Comment: Did add the reference Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient into your  project?